# opencv3.0.0 BackgroundSubtractor::apply leads to "R6025 pure virtual function call"

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, background-subtraction

I'm running the [**BackgroundSubtractor demo**](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/video/bg_sub.cpp) in **opencv3.0-gold-release** with **vs2013**, while the following error occurs when exiting the program:
[image]

the callstack is as follows:

```
cv3_bg_sub.exe!cv::MatAllocator::unmap(cv::UMatData * u) 行 62   C++
cv3_bg_sub.exe!cv::Mat::deallocate() 行 433  C++
cv3_bg_sub.exe!cv::Mat::release() 行 668 C++
cv3_bg_sub.exe!cv::Mat::~Mat() 行 555    C++
```

The var `this` in the auto-window shows inconsistently:
[image]

Anyone who has experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was finally solved by changing lib dependencies from `staticlib` to dynamic libs, seems the **pre-built staticlib** is buggy (anyone who has the same experience?)

I've rebuilt (both static and dynamic) opencv300 source code on my own, and the errors are gone.